# Column Generation?

Tags: integer-programming, discrete-optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I implemented a method to solve a large integer program but am not sure how its called.
The idea is the same as column generation, just less explicit.

Take the following problem as a simple example (optimal solution [1,0,0]):

(1)

min $\sum_n n x_n$

s.t.

$\sum_n x_n = 1$

$x_n \in \{0,1\}, \forall n$

Let n be a vector [1,2,3].

---

Now, using column generation I would generate all permutations $[a_1, a_2, a_3]_{1...k}$, such that $\sum_n a_{n,k} = 1, \forall k \land a_{n,k} \in \{0,1\}, \forall n,k$ and add them iteratively. Variable $y_k$ now denotes whether a permutation $k$ is selected. This yields:

min $\sum_n n x_n$

s.t.

$a_k \circ y_k = x, \forall k$

$\sum_k y_k = 1$

$y_k \in \{0,1\}^{k}, \forall n$

(2) It can be proven computationally that a solution is a global minimum by generating and evaluating all permutations.

But I can expect first improvements quite fast (usually).

---

To decrease computational cost I am only interested in a subset of all permutations. However, I don't want to generate all permutations manually but let the solver do it. Hence, I change this algorithm described in (2) by utilising model (1).

Assume I know a solution $x'$.

During the first iteration, I then solve:

min $n_1 x_1 + \sum_2^n n x'_n$

s.t.

$x_1 + \sum_2^n x'_n = 1$

$x_1 \in \{0,1\}$

During the second iteration I solve:

min $n_1 x_1 + n_2 x_2 + \sum_3^n n x'_n$

s.t.

$x_1 + x_2 + \sum_3^n x'_n = 1$

$x_1, x_2 \in \{0,1\}$

and so forth.

Eventually I will solve model 1 entirely and be able obtain an optimal solution - given enough time.
Does this classify as column-and-constraint generation?
I start from a fixed solution and reintruduce integer variables, eventually recovering the full problem.

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: Did you instead mean $x_n \ge 0$ and integer?

Comment: Yes, it is binary.

Comment: But you say $[3,0,0]$ is optimal.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I messed that up. I changed it to [1,0,0]

Comment: This sounds a bit like a form of neighborhood search. You're not adding columns. Rather, you are fixing some variables at their values in the initial solution $x^\prime$ and gradually relaxing those restrictions.

Comment: Thank you! You are right, the idea is exactly the same as neighborhood search. But I am generating new columns every iteration because, say for iteration 1, I can rewrite the constraint as

$x1 = 1 - \sum_2^n x'_n$

Everything is moved into the RHS. When implementing I decided against simply fixing variables, because I wanted to keep the constraint matrix as concise as possible.

Then for iteration 2, I get $x_1 + x_2 = 1 - \sum_3^n x'_n$

Comment: I think my latest response is flawed regarding how the the models are constructed and simply by the fact that I am relying on branch-and-bound by the solver. Does column generation require an implementation that just adds a column and or constraint to the constraint matrix, to then do at most one pivot to move the variable into the basis?